# EWS Operation Item.Copy fails with 'full_access_as_app' permission

Tags: permissions, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, copying

We have been using the [EWS Item.Copy Operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.copy?view=exchange-ews-api#microsoft-exchange-webservices-data-item-copy(microsoft-exchange-webservices-data-folderid)) for nearly 5 years. Since last week (Monday 26th of February 18:00 CET) this operation started failing for 2 of our 40 customers. No configuration has changed in Azure. App Secrets and API Permissions are setup correctly and consent has been given once more to be sure. We ask our customers to grant us 'full_access_as_app', which should be enough for the [EWS Item.Copy Operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.copy?view=exchange-ews-api#microsoft-exchange-webservices-data-item-copy(microsoft-exchange-webservices-data-folderid)) and this has been enough for years.

Unfortunately for 2 customers the EWS API is denying us acces. I can get the message to be copied and I can get the target folder I want to copy the message to. But a copy operation throws the following error:

> reason="Access to this API requires the following permissions:
> 'MailExport-Internal.Read.All,MailExport-Internal.Read.Shared,MailExport-Internal.ReadWrite.All,MailExport-Internal.ReadWrite.Shared'.
> However, the application only has the following permissions granted:
> 'full_access_as_app'."
> error_category="invalid_grant"

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I have tested that I can get the message and target folder through the EWS API using Postman.
I have renewed the App Secrets.
I have checked all permissions requested and consent has been withdrawn and given to be sure.
I have created a new mailbox to test if the target is an issue.

The problem still persists, even between other mailboxes and folders.

Comment: Having the same issue, any progress on this?

Comment: Microsoft support is pointing us to the exchange admin centre. There you can create a new role and add the Import export permission. Unfortunately this role can only be assigned to users or exchange service accounts. We are using Entra ID App Registrations as authentication/authorization. We have chosen to refactor the code to the Create Message Graph operation.

Comment: We used [this MS Forum question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1103509/save-mail-to-inbox-using-graph-api-similar-to-exch) to successfully create a sent e-mail in a user's mailbox folder. Make sure you set CreatedDateTime and LastModifiedDateTime to the original datetime otherwise the e-mail will be created with datetime 'today'.

Comment: Thanks, am waiting for MS Support to take my case so will see what they say. Was considering using the graph method create message under folder (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) which didn't appear to have the limitation of needing to start as a draft message. It's kinda ridiculous that this just breaks and they give an unworking solution for your setup

Comment: Just had MS on the phone and when we tried to reproduce the issue seems to have resolved itself

Comment: Good to hear. I'm glad we've migrated to Graph just in time as the problem started to occur for all of our customers. So far so good...